# How to determine if a file will be logically moved or physically moved

Tags: java, file-io, filesystems, nio

**The facts:**

When a file is moved, there's two possibilities:

1. The source and destination file are on the same partition and only the file system index is updated
2. The source and destination are on two different file system and the file need to be moved byte per byte. (aka copy on move)

**The question:**

How can I determine if a file will be either logically or physically moved ?

I'm transferring large files (700+ megs) and would adopt a different behaviors for each situation.

---

Edit:

I've already coded a moving file dialog with a worker thread that perform the blocking io call to copy the file a meg at a time. It provide information to the user like rough estimate of the remaining time and transfer rate.

**The problem is: how do I know if the file can be moved logically before trying to move it physically ?**

Comment: You are making the mistaken assumption that a file move on the same partition is merely a change in the metadata. This is not necessarily true on NTFS. Moving a file in or out a compressed directory can cause a physical copy to (de)compress the file. Similarly, encrypted directories can cause physical copies to (de)crypt the file.

Comment: You are right, a copy/delete operation might be needed within the same NTFS partiton. But still, my goal was to determine if a copy/delete would be needed or a simple metadata change would do the job to move the file. The accepted solution addresses this problem. If you have other question or others solutions, feel free to contribute. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I'm on something :)

Using **[JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/)** I am able to **call the Win32 API** (and *nix API too) **from java**.

I tried calling `GetFileInformationByHandle` and did got a result BUT the `dwVolumeSerialNumber` attribute always equals 0 (tried with my C: and D: drive)

Then I saw this function on MSDN: [`MoveFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240(VS.85,loband).aspx). When the flag parametter is set to 0, the copy on move feature will be disable. **AND IT WORKS !!!!**

So I will simply call

```
if (!Kernel32.INSTANCE.MoveFileEx(source.getAbsolutePath(), destination.getAbsolutePath(), 0)) {
    System.out.println("logical move failed");
}
```

Here is the code to put in the `Kernel32.java` interface (this file can be found in the src.zip package in the download section of the **[JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/)** site):

```
boolean MoveFileEx(String lpExistingFileName, String lpNewFileName, int dwFlags);

int MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING = 0x01;
int MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED = 0x02;
int MOVEFILE_CREATE_HARDLINK = 0x04;
int MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH = 0x08;
int MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT = 0x10;
int MOVEFILE_FAIL_IF_NOT_TRACKABLE = 0x20;
```

Comment: +1, MoveFileEx() is a good find. I'm curious though: how are you getting the HANDLE value to call GetFileInformationByHandle() with? The dwVolumeSerialNumber entry is populated sensibly in my C++ test program (i.e. it's a nonzero value, different for different drives).

Comment: I got it using CreateFile wich return a file handle. When you call CreateFile, you have to specify that a new file must not be created so it will fail if the file does not exist.

Comment: Hmm... CreateFile() is the right way to get a HANDLE, but I'm a bit puzzled as to why you talked about specifying that a new file must not be created -- are you possibly trying to open the destination *file* (which doesn't exist yet), instead of the destination *directory*?

Comment: Actually, I was comparing two files on two differents disks so for my little test, I didin't want to create a new file. But you're right, in the case we are interested in, it would make sense to create the target file at this stage.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux or other *nices, call `stat()` on the source and destination directories and compare their `st_dev` values.  If they are the same, a logical move can be performed, otherwise a physical copy+delete must be performed.

On Windows, you can call `GetFileInformationByHandle()` on handles to the two directories and compare their `dwVolumeSerialNumber` values.  Note that this requires Windows 2000 or later.

I see you're using Java -- there must be some portal through which you can access this OS-level info (perhaps JNI?)

Comment: Wow, impressive :) I'll try to find more information about that. Thank you !

Comment: I hope it helps, but I can't guarantee that these conditions will hold -- it just makes sense that they would ;)

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm currently looking toward JNA (https://jna.dev.java.net/) for kernel32 and unix API access.

Comment: @Blade: By all means, it's the answer that worked for you! :)