# java: check if a file can be moved under windows

Tags: java, windows, permissions

I need to rename a file (keeping it in the same directory);
I can't seem to find a way to see if my program has the required permissions:

```
Files.isWritable(directory) && Files.isWritable(oldFile);
```

always returns true, wether or not the running user has the permission to write the file (I guess they only check if the file is read-only, even if this violates the contract stated in the javadoc);
I'm not running under a security manager so I can't call

```
System.getSecurityManager.checkDelete(oldFile.toString());
```

I need to check if the renaming of several files will (probably) succeed so I can't just try and catch the exception.
Is there a way out? Obviously a portable solution would be lovable but I would settle for a windows-specific one...

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736859/how-to-determine-if-a-file-will-be-logically-moved-or-physically-moved

Comment: This might help you.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736859/how-to-determine-if-a-file-will-be-logically-moved-or-physically-moved]

Comment: Well, for "probably" I think the `canWrite()`- and `exists()`- and `isDirectory()`- (and similar) methods are sufficient. And if you want to rename I would recommend a try-catch-block, because with IO I'd always use a try-catch-block (there are many things that can go wrong)... With your exact code, it would be easier to give a more precise answer though.

Comment: @AnanthaKrishnan

I would avoid having to call native methods just to check if I can write a file, it seems rather obtuse...

Comment: @ALexS
I would suppose that the old IO api yelds the same results as the new one, so path.toFile().canWrite() shoud return true iff Files.isWritable(path) returns true...

Comment: @lultimouomo I never was suggesting something different. My intention was to say:    If you only need the information if renaming will PROBABLY work, these functions (or equivalents) are sufficient. But this means it is also possible that the test returns true and it won't work.    But you should not only test `oldFile` and `directory`, but also `newFile` (and its `newDirectory`) since these can be errorcauses, too.    Without your exact code, nobody will be able to tell you if you missed a crucial test.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't check Windows ACLs that way. The "native" solution is fairly easy, since Windows supports transactions on the file system. Just call `DeleteFileTransacted`, and roll back the transaction if any one deletion fails.

If you're not using tranactions, then the second option is to first open handles with explicit `DELETE` desired access (`DELETE` is one of the standard WinNT access rights), denying any sharing. If and only if this succeeds for all files, delete them all with `SetFileInformationByHandle(handle, FileDispositionInfo, &fdiObj, sizeof(fdiObj));`

(The latter is not a transaction and may have Isolation issues as a result, which in turn affect Atomicity).

Comment: Turns out you can, with java7:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815523/reading-windows-acls-from-java
Anyway, this answer put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try `new SecurityManager().checkDelete(oldFile.toString())`.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to move it! If the move failed, you didn't have permissions, or something else went wrong.

This is a general principle. Don't try to foretell the future, guessing whether an impending operation will succeed. Try the operation. Otherwise you introduce all sorts of extra problems:

1. You might make the wrong test.
2. The condition might change between the test and the operation.
3. The operation usually returns an error or throws an exception anyway, which you have to write code to handle: why write it all twice?

Comment: Because as I write in the question
"I need to check if the renaming of several files will (probably) succeed so I can't just try and catch the exception."
I need some kind of transactional integrity, distributed over filesystem operations and database updates.
It does not need (nor can, probably) have real ACID guarantees, but a forewarn when things are bound to go wrong (i.e. because you don't have write permissions on the filesystem) would be in order.